# Does compiler generates specific code for template code in CPP based on template instantiation?

Tags: c++

Does compiler generates specific code for the template code in C++? For e.g. if a template is instantiated for int - an int version will be generated by the compiler. I thought, it does but I can't see that generated code anywhere in the source code?

Vehicle.h

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

template <class T> 

class Vehicle
{

private:

    T m_x;
    T m_y;


public:
    static T val;
    Vehicle(T x, T y);

    Vehicle();

    ~Vehicle();

    T add();

};

#endif
```

Vehicle.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
Vehicle<T>::Vehicle(T x, T y): m_x(x), m_y(y)
{
    std::cout << "Parameterised constructor called" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>

Vehicle<T>::Vehicle()
{
    std::cout << "Calling default constructor" << std::endl;
}
template <class T>
Vehicle<T>::~Vehicle()
{
    std::cout << "Calling destructor" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>

T Vehicle<T>::add()
{
    return m_x + m_y;
}
```

Now, the file that instantiate specific code -

```
#include "Vehicle.cpp"

template class Vehicle<int>;
template class Vehicle<float>;
```

I am using visual studio to compile and link the code. After reading about templates - https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_122.html

Comment: Why would you expect to see the code generated from templates in the source code? The compiler compiles your source code. It generates code from your source code. It does not rewrite your source code…

Comment: Do you *use* the resulting classes anywhere? If it's compiled to an executable that never uses the classes, the object code would never be needed, so it (machine code corresponding to the realized template) wouldn't show up in the final executable. If you're expecting actual C++ source code to appear somewhere, that's not how templates work (it's not like C preprocessor macros where you can run the preprocessor on the file and see the result of expanding the macros).